# ERRO: Função incorreta

Tags: php, mysql

Desenvolvi um portal e ele funciona corretamente no localhost, mas quando fui colocá-lo no ar, parou de funcionar a conexão com o banco. Então ao tentar realizar a conexão com o banco ele não loga no portal, apenas abre uma página em branco escrito **Função Incorreta**. Não consigo descobrir porque isso ocorre, a princípio a conexão está correta. Segue abaixo a conexão:

```
  $conexao = mysqli_connect('mysql.site.com.br','user','12345') or print(mysqli_error());
  $db      = mysqli_select_db($conexao, 'banco_teste') or print(mysqli_error());
```

Aceito sugestões do que posso fazer para funcionar. Obrigada!

Comment: Precisa olha o log de erros do apache.

Comment: E como eu posso fazer isso?

Comment: Já comparou as versões dos PHP local e externo?

Comment: Eu não sei como descobrir a versão do externo, do local já sei.

Comment: Eu tive um probleminha parecido, e se tratava de versão do PHP. Tente verificar isso.

Comment: Ok, obrigado pela sugestão. Irei tentar descobrir

Comment: O problema realmente era a versão de PHP.

Answer (score 3):

A função "*mysqli_select_db()*" só deve ser usado para alterar a database padrão definido no "*mysqli_connect()*", **você deve definir o banco de dados no 4º parâmetro do "*mysqli_connect()*"**, ou seja,

```
$conexao = mysqli_connect('mysql.site.com.br','user','12345', 'banco_teste') or die(mysqli_error());
```

Também deixo a dica para substituir o "*print(mysqli_error())*" para "*die()*", assim você já encerra o código PHP de ser executado e evita futuros erros e um log gigantesco de erros salvo no servidor.